# How to use an existing field value with $push in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following Mongo collection

```
{
      "_id": ObjectId("5524d12d2702a21830bdb8e5"),
      "code": "Apple",
      "name": "iPhone",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "code": "xxx",
          "name": "Andrew",
          "value": "9",
          
        },
        {
          "code": "yyy",
          "name": "Joy",
          "value": "7",
          
        },
        
      ]
    }
```

I am using the following query to push into the parameters array object

```
db.coll.update({
  "parameters.name": "Andrew"
},
{
  $push: {
    "parameters": {
      "code": "$code",
      "name": "bar",
      "value": "10",
      
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

However, for the value of `code`, I want to use the value of the object that matched (i.e. the object with `parameters.name == "Andrew"`, which here is `xxx`.

Here's a playground link to the problem https://mongoplayground.net/p/v-j1tCCjiWq
Also, I am using a really old version (3.2) of MongoDb. It would be preferable if the solution worked with that.

Comment: I think you will need to resort to js/application level manipulation for such an old version of MongoDB

Comment: @ray What is the minimum version of MongoDb will I need to solve this directly? And how would that solution look like?

Comment: or maybe actually something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GMvyXH1S6Y4). Since you match `code` by the value "xxx" anyway, the value you targeting for will always be "xxx"

Comment: @ray But I would eventually want to match with some other field like `name`. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The point is you match by some constant value. If you get a result, the value matched will always be the constant value you specified. So for your case, you can just reuse the same constant value in your `$push` clause.

Comment: @ray No, that is clearly not the case. Please read the updated question. The constant value specified is from the matched object, it is not the value matched.

Comment: I asked the same question in the MongoDB Developer Community and got the answer there https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-use-an-existing-field-value-with-push-in-mongodb/211961/2?u=manak_bisht

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v4.4+, you can first `$match` with your criteria. Chain up `$first` with `$filter` to extract the array element you want. Use `$concatArrays` to append a new element(i.e. same as `$push`) to the array and `$merge` to update back into the collection.

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "parameters.name": "Andrew"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      parameters: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$parameters",
          [
            {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                // get the object matched
                {
                  "$first": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$parameters",
                      "as": "p",
                      "cond": {
                        $eq: [
                          "Andrew",
                          "$$p.name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                // update the object matched with other fields with constant value
                {
                  "name": "bar",
                  "value": "10"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "coll1",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dpUZUVm9MTS)